# My Ubuntu webserver serves the wrong content

Tags: ubuntu, web-server

We host our website in an internal physical server, we are using Ubuntu Server 16.10.
The website actually is not reachable via domain name or public IP address, but I can reach it when I use local network of the server (192.168.1.2).
When I use curl command to browse the site (domain name or public IP) via server terminal, it gives an html page, contains a form and a javascript code trying (the code)  to fin and md5 string.
I tried to change Document Root first time via apache site-enabled, then I stopped apache, but curl  still gives me this html page.
I trey to re-verify my public address via curl ipinfo.io/ip it still the same.
I moved the html page code my lapatop, I run it in the browser, it's a js script to get MD5 hash.
Please what the steps I have to follow to slove this problem?
Bellow the code

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<!--- Page(9097)=[Ouverture de session] --->
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
/*
 * A JavaScript implementation of the RSA Data Security, Inc. MD5 Message
 * Digest Algorithm, as defined in RFC 1321.
 * Version 2.1 Copyright (C) Paul Johnston 1999 - 2002.
 * Other contributors: Greg Holt, Andrew Kepert, Ydnar, Lostinet
 * Distributed under the BSD License
 * See http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5 for more info.
 */

/*
 * Configurable variables. You may need to tweak these to be compatible with
 * the server-side, but the defaults work in most cases.
 */
var hexcase = 0;  /* hex output format. 0 - lowercase; 1 - uppercase        */
var b64pad  = ""; /* base-64 pad character. "=" for strict RFC compliance   */
var chrsz   = 8;  /* bits per input character. 8 - ASCII; 16 - Unicode      */

/*
 * These are the functions you'll usually want to call
 * They take string arguments and return either hex or base-64 encoded strings
 */
function hex_md5(s){ return binl2hex(core_md5(str2binl(s), s.length * chrsz));}
function b64_md5(s){ return binl2b64(core_md5(str2binl(s), s.length * chrsz));}
function str_md5(s){ return binl2str(core_md5(str2binl(s), s.length * chrsz));}
function hex_hmac_md5(key, data) { return binl2hex(core_hmac_md5(key, data)); }
function b64_hmac_md5(key, data) { return binl2b64(core_hmac_md5(key, data)); }
function str_hmac_md5(key, data) { return binl2str(core_hmac_md5(key, data)); }

/* 
 * Perform a simple self-test to see if the VM is working 
 */
function md5_vm_test()
{
  return hex_md5("abc") == "900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72";
}

/*
 * Calculate the MD5 of an array of little-endian words, and a bit length
 */
function core_md5(x, len)
{
  /* append padding */
  x[len >> 5] |= 0x80 << ((len) % 32);
  x[(((len + 64) >>> 9) << 4) + 14] = len;

  var a =  1732584193;
  var b = -271733879;
  var c = -1732584194;
  var d =  271733878;

  for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i += 16)
  {
    var olda = a;
    var oldb = b;
    var oldc = c;
    var oldd = d;

    a = md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 0], 7 , -680876936);
    d = md5_ff(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 1], 12, -389564586);
    c = md5_ff(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 2], 17,  606105819);
    b = md5_ff(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 3], 22, -1044525330);
    a = md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 4], 7 , -176418897);
    d = md5_ff(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 5], 12,  1200080426);
    c = md5_ff(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 6], 17, -1473231341);
    b = md5_ff(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 7], 22, -45705983);
    a = md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 8], 7 ,  1770035416);
    d = md5_ff(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 9], 12, -1958414417);
    c = md5_ff(c, d, a, b, x[i+10], 17, -42063);
    b = md5_ff(b, c, d, a, x[i+11], 22, -1990404162);
    a = md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x[i+12], 7 ,  1804603682);
    d = md5_ff(d, a, b, c, x[i+13], 12, -40341101);
    c = md5_ff(c, d, a, b, x[i+14], 17, -1502002290);
    b = md5_ff(b, c, d, a, x[i+15], 22,  1236535329);

    a = md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 1], 5 , -165796510);
    d = md5_gg(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 6], 9 , -1069501632);
    c = md5_gg(c, d, a, b, x[i+11], 14,  643717713);
    b = md5_gg(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 0], 20, -373897302);
    a = md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 5], 5 , -701558691);
    d = md5_gg(d, a, b, c, x[i+10], 9 ,  38016083);
    c = md5_gg(c, d, a, b, x[i+15], 14, -660478335);
    b = md5_gg(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 4], 20, -405537848);
    a = md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 9], 5 ,  568446438);
    d = md5_gg(d, a, b, c, x[i+14], 9 , -1019803690);
    c = md5_gg(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 3], 14, -187363961);
    b = md5_gg(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 8], 20,  1163531501);
    a = md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x[i+13], 5 , -1444681467);
    d = md5_gg(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 2], 9 , -51403784);
    c = md5_gg(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 7], 14,  1735328473);
    b = md5_gg(b, c, d, a, x[i+12], 20, -1926607734);

    a = md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 5], 4 , -378558);
    d = md5_hh(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 8], 11, -2022574463);
    c = md5_hh(c, d, a, b, x[i+11], 16,  1839030562);
    b = md5_hh(b, c, d, a, x[i+14], 23, -35309556);
    a = md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 1], 4 , -1530992060);
    d = md5_hh(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 4], 11,  1272893353);
    c = md5_hh(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 7], 16, -155497632);
    b = md5_hh(b, c, d, a, x[i+10], 23, -1094730640);
    a = md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x[i+13], 4 ,  681279174);
    d = md5_hh(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 0], 11, -358537222);
    c = md5_hh(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 3], 16, -722521979);
    b = md5_hh(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 6], 23,  76029189);
    a = md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 9], 4 , -640364487);
    d = md5_hh(d, a, b, c, x[i+12], 11, -421815835);
    c = md5_hh(c, d, a, b, x[i+15], 16,  530742520);
    b = md5_hh(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 2], 23, -995338651);

    a = md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 0], 6 , -198630844);
    d = md5_ii(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 7], 10,  1126891415);
    c = md5_ii(c, d, a, b, x[i+14], 15, -1416354905);
    b = md5_ii(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 5], 21, -57434055);
    a = md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x[i+12], 6 ,  1700485571);
    d = md5_ii(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 3], 10, -1894986606);
    c = md5_ii(c, d, a, b, x[i+10], 15, -1051523);
    b = md5_ii(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 1], 21, -2054922799);
    a = md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 8], 6 ,  1873313359);
    d = md5_ii(d, a, b, c, x[i+15], 10, -30611744);
    c = md5_ii(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 6], 15, -1560198380);
    b = md5_ii(b, c, d, a, x[i+13], 21,  1309151649);
    a = md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 4], 6 , -145523070);
    d = md5_ii(d, a, b, c, x[i+11], 10, -1120210379);
    c = md5_ii(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 2], 15,  718787259);
    b = md5_ii(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 9], 21, -343485551);

    a = safe_add(a, olda);
    b = safe_add(b, oldb);
    c = safe_add(c, oldc);
    d = safe_add(d, oldd);
  }
  return Array(a, b, c, d);

}

/*
 * These functions implement the four basic operations the algorithm uses.
 */
function md5_cmn(q, a, b, x, s, t)
{
  return safe_add(bit_rol(safe_add(safe_add(a, q), safe_add(x, t)), s),b);
}
function md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x, s, t)
{
  return md5_cmn((b & c) | ((~b) & d), a, b, x, s, t);
}
function md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x, s, t)
{
  return md5_cmn((b & d) | (c & (~d)), a, b, x, s, t);
}
function md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x, s, t)
{
  return md5_cmn(b ^ c ^ d, a, b, x, s, t);
}
function md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x, s, t)
{
  return md5_cmn(c ^ (b | (~d)), a, b, x, s, t);
}

/*
 * Calculate the HMAC-MD5, of a key and some data
 */
function core_hmac_md5(key, data)
{
  var bkey = str2binl(key);
  if(bkey.length > 16) bkey = core_md5(bkey, key.length * chrsz);

  var ipad = Array(16), opad = Array(16);
  for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++) 
  {
    ipad[i] = bkey[i] ^ 0x36363636;
    opad[i] = bkey[i] ^ 0x5C5C5C5C;
  }

  var hash = core_md5(ipad.concat(str2binl(data)), 512 + data.length * chrsz);
  return core_md5(opad.concat(hash), 512 + 128);
}

/*
 * Add integers, wrapping at 2^32. This uses 16-bit operations internally
 * to work around bugs in some JS interpreters.
 */
function safe_add(x, y)
{
  var lsw = (x & 0xFFFF) + (y & 0xFFFF);
  var msw = (x >> 16) + (y >> 16) + (lsw >> 16);
  return (msw << 16) | (lsw & 0xFFFF);
}

/*
 * Bitwise rotate a 32-bit number to the left.
 */
function bit_rol(num, cnt)
{
  return (num << cnt) | (num >>> (32 - cnt));
}

/*
 * Convert a string to an array of little-endian words
 * If chrsz is ASCII, characters >255 have their hi-byte silently ignored.
 */
function str2binl(str)
{
  var bin = Array();
  var mask = (1 << chrsz) - 1;
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length * chrsz; i += chrsz)
    bin[i>>5] |= (str.charCodeAt(i / chrsz) & mask) << (i%32);
  return bin;
}

/*
 * Convert an array of little-endian words to a string
 */
function binl2str(bin)
{
  var str = "";
  var mask = (1 << chrsz) - 1;
  for(var i = 0; i < bin.length * 32; i += chrsz)
    str += String.fromCharCode((bin[i>>5] >>> (i % 32)) & mask);
  return str;
}

/*
 * Convert an array of little-endian words to a hex string.
 */
function binl2hex(binarray)
{
  var hex_tab = hexcase ? "0123456789ABCDEF" : "0123456789abcdef";
  var str = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < binarray.length * 4; i++)
  {
    str += hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i>>2] >> ((i%4)*8+4)) & 0xF) +
           hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i>>2] >> ((i%4)*8  )) & 0xF);
  }
  return str;
}

/*
 * Convert an array of little-endian words to a base-64 string
 */
function binl2b64(binarray)
{
  var tab = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
  var str = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < binarray.length * 4; i += 3)
  {
    var triplet = (((binarray[i   >> 2] >> 8 * ( i   %4)) & 0xFF) << 16)
                | (((binarray[i+1 >> 2] >> 8 * ((i+1)%4)) & 0xFF) << 8 )
                |  ((binarray[i+2 >> 2] >> 8 * ((i+2)%4)) & 0xFF);
    for(var j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
      if(i * 8 + j * 6 > binarray.length * 32) str += b64pad;
      else str += tab.charAt((triplet >> 6*(3-j)) & 0x3F);
    }
  }
  return str;
}

function SendPassword()
{
    var tmp;
    document.form_contents.elements['md5_pass'].value=document.form_contents.elements['password_1115706115'].value+document.form_contents.elements['auth_key'].value
    tmp=hex_md5(document.form_contents.elements['md5_pass'].value);
    document.form_contents.elements['md5_pass'].value=tmp;
    document.form_contents.elements['password_1115706115'].value="";
    mimic_button('submit_button_login_submit: ..', 0);
}

var is_button_in_focus=false;
var is_submit=0;

function loaded()
{
  var inp;
  document.form_contents.mimic_button_field.value="";
  if (inp)
  {
    inp.focus();
  }
}
function keyDown(e)
{
  var button_no;
  return true;
  switch(button_no)
  {
  case 13:
    if (is_button_in_focus)
      return true;
    javascript:SendPassword();
    return false;
  case 32:
    if (is_button_in_focus)
    {
    javascript:SendPassword();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  default:
    return true;
  }
}

document.onkeydown=keyDown;
function mimic_button(button_name, cgi)
{
  if (is_submit)
    return;
  is_submit=1;
  f=document.form_contents;
  switch(cgi) {
  case 0:
    f.encoding="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    f.action="/cache/33662975/index.cgi";
    break;
  case 2:
    f.encoding="multipart/form-data";
    f.action="/cache/375823738/index.cgi";
    break;
  }
  f.mimic_button_field.value = button_name;
  setTimeout("is_submit=0", 1000);
  f.submit();
}
function ChClassButton(Mybutton , newClass)
{
      if (document.getElementById)
    {
       document.getElementById(Mybutton).className = newClass;
    }
}
function lb_mimic_button(button_name, cgi, buttName)
{
  if (buttState[buttName] == 0)
    return;
  if (is_submit)
    return;
  is_submit=1;
  f=document.form_contents;
  switch(cgi) {
  case 0:
    f.encoding="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    f.action="/cache/6713098/index.cgi";
    break;
  case 2:
    f.encoding="multipart/form-data";
    f.action="/cache/1478897698/index.cgi";
    break;
  }
  f.mimic_button_field.value = button_name;
  setTimeout("is_submit=0", 1000);
  f.submit();
}

// -->
</script>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Wed, 04 Jan 2017 09:54:13 GMT"/>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta name="author" content="Sagem Communications"/>
<meta name="Copyright" content="Sagem Communications"/>
<title>FAST3304-V2</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/fonts.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/generic.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/page.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="form_contents" method="post" action="/cache/1968501236/index.cgi" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onSubmit="if (window.is_submit && is_submit==1) return false; is_submit=1; return true; ">
<!-- lb_struct_cb -->
<div class="main">

<table class="contener">
<tr>
<td rowspan="2" id="menu">
<div id="logo">
<img src="/cache/02-Dec-10 15:29:11/images/logo.gif"/>
&nbsp;</div>
</td>
<td rowspan="2" class="space">
&nbsp;</td>
<td class="panel">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="content">
<table class="content">
<tr><td>
<div id="content">

<p class="title">
Ouverture de session</p>
<!-- p_scr_login -->
<input type="hidden" name="active_page" value="9097"/><input type="hidden" name="session_id" value="1115706115"/><input type="hidden" name="prev_page" value="0"/><input type="hidden" name="page_title" value="Ouverture de session"/><input type="hidden" name="nav_stack_0" value="9097"/><input type="hidden" name="mimic_button_field" value=""/><input type="hidden" name="button_value" value=""/><input type="hidden" name="transaction_id" value="0"/><!-- lb_page_start_cb -->
<div id="login">
<table class="login">
<tr>
<td>Langage</td>
<td><select name="lang" onchange="javascript:mimic_button('Sur le Changements: lang..')"><option  value="0">EN  English</option><option selected value="1">FR  French</option></select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="libelle">Identifiant</td>
<td class="field"><input type="text" style="WIDTH: 150px" name="user_name" value="" size=20 maxlength=64></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="libelle">Mot de passe</td>
<td class="field"><input type="password" style="WIDTH: 150px" name="password_1115706115" value="" size=20 maxlength=64><input type="hidden" name="md5_pass" value=""/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="auth_key" value="1891832742"/><!-- p_buttons_array -->
<p class="submit"><input type="button"  onclick="javascript:SendPassword()" value="  OK  " style="{width:120px;}" class="button" ></input></p>
</div>

</td></tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

After Seeing Gerald Schneider Answer, I was sure that's my router login page appear instead my site.
To make sure that's a router problem, I shutdown the server, the public IP address still show the router config login page.
There is no IP confilt, Server local address is 192.168.1.2, and router loccal address is 192.168.1.1.

Comment: Format the server and restore from backups.

Answer (score 10):

This doesn't look hacked. It looks like the login screen to a connected device on your network. Sagem Communications (mentioned in the meta tags) manufactures set top boxes, routers etc. My guess would be that you added a device to your network recently and it has the same IP address as your server.

According to the title tag the device is  a FAST3304-V2 router.

It's hard to give advice without knowing your network, I'll try to give some general hints on what you can do:

- Figure out if you are really accessing your server or said router. If it is the router, check the network configuration of both devices and make sure they have different network addresses
- It could be a DNS problem, for example the router sending you to the wrong address for the server name you want. If this is the case it should be easily fixed by defining the correct DNS entry
- If you are actually accessing the server and it still sends you the router login form, check the configuration of your server. The httpd my be configured to proxy requests, iptables could be configured to redirect packets, there are many possibilities

You will have to do more investigating, without knowing more about your setup this is just blind guessing.

Comment: Good catch! Or it acts as a second DHCP server overriding the original network config

Comment: You are right, How I can fix it?

Comment: @learner123 I added some general hints, it's hard to give concrete advice with the given information

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I updated my question, I shutdown the server and I still able to reach my router admin page via the public ip. the local addresses are not the same. so what router config I hv to set?

Comment: It solved, I just had to forward 80 on my router, It was opened, I don't what is happened<br>.
Thank you so much to @Gerald Schneider who is helped me by his answer.